# Why is my code doing a Bad Request bad URI [object%20Object]?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am using jquery to fire an ajax request when check box is changed to alter the boolean attribute 'completed' on resource 'Task'. I have the following code regarding AJAX part, but I get this error > **bad URI `/projects/1/tasks/[object%20Object]'**

**tasks.js.coffee**

```
    $('#task_completed').bind 'change', (event) =>
      url = $('#task_completed').closest('form').attr('action')
      data = {}
      data.task = {}
      $.post({
        url: url
        data: data
        success: ->
          $('.task_headline').toggleClass('completed_task')
      })
```

**task/show.html.erb**

```
       <%= form_for [@project, @task], :remote => true do |f| %>
         <%= f.label :completed %>       
         <%= f.check_box :completed %> <!-- this automatically has the id="task_completed" -->
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to specify data, don't specify data.

```
    $('#task_completed').bind 'change', (event) =>
      url = $('#task_completed').closest('form').attr('action')

      $.post({
        url: url
        success: ->
          $('.task_headline').toggleClass('completed_task')
      })
```

Also, you are forgetting a comma behind url:url, which might be necessary.

```
    $('#task_completed').bind 'change', (event) =>
      url = $('#task_completed').closest('form').attr('action')

      $.post({
        url: url,
        success: ->
          $('.task_headline').toggleClass('completed_task')
      })
```

If it still happens then, you'll want to replace the function temporarily by:

```js
window.alert($('#task_completed').closest('form').attr('action'))
```

If this shows `[object%20Object]` in the alert then there's something wrong where you are saving the form. Please note that `[object%20Object]` means that you are trying to print out an object which has no explicit toString() defined. This is exactly what happens when you try to convert `{}` to a string.

Don't believe me? Copy the following to your address bar and hit enter:

```
javascript:var test = {};window.alert(test.toString());
```

Comment: @oFca: Because it can't find the action, can you show us your generated HTML?

Comment: but when I put this window.alert inside .bind, than it says 'projects/1/tasks/4', wich are my resources and their id's. what now?

Comment: @minitech: It could be optional, but I haven't learned CoffeeScript that much. But I do know that if you add it, you should be safe.